# How to create a new Laravel project in PhpStorm 2018.1?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, ubuntu-16.04

How to create a new Laravel project in PhpStorm 2018.1 (in Ubuntu 16.04)?

Comment: Just do it in console using composer (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installing-laravel) andthen just tell PhpStorm to open that folder -- it will create new project from those files. Or if you really want to make it from within PhpStorm -- use "New Project" and then "Composer Project" and specify `laravel/laravel` as a package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a PhpStorm specific question. To create a new project you need to have composer installed

[Composer Homepage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#downloading-the-composer-executable)

and be sure it's appended to your path.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

To accept the changes, run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or logout and login again.

Then have a look at the Laravel documentation

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation)

There are 2 possible ways:

- Use composer directly
- Use the Laravel installer

Both ways are fine, open the new created project in PhpStorm and you are good to go.

Answer (score 19):

It's just a five step process,

Just go to File -> New Project and in the dialog specify project name and folder, and – most importantly – choose type Composer Project.

> [image]

1. Set Laravel project's folder & project name
2. Choose "composer.phar" option button & tick "Download composer.phar from getcomposer.org"
3. Select PHP Interpreter Version from drop down
4. Select package as "laravel/laravel" from list
5. Select PHP's version

Click on "Create" button. It will take time depending on your internet connection speed.

> [image]

Congratulations, your new laravel project has been created.

[image]

Comment: It worked ok first time with a initial project. But later, second time when I created another project it started to  abuse like **composer:** `Failed to run 'create-project' command` . Then I didnt choose "composer.phar" and the error gone